# Convert Empty string into NULL when data insert into table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I am stuck on inserting data from one table into another table and exporting data into csv file using `bcp`. The problem is that the csv text file contains `null` instead of '' empty string.

When I insert data into a table from another table the empty string column is treated as a `NULL`. Doing the `bcp` command generate correct file.

I am using this command to export bcp

```
bcp ClientReportNewOrder out "D:\Temp\Neeraj\TestResults\oOR.txt" -c -t"," -r"\n" -S"." -U"sa" -P"123"
```

and  this for insert data into table

```
insert into ClientReportNewOrder
    select * from ClientReportNewOrder_import
```

Comment: Why can't use NULLIF(Col1,NULL) while inserting into table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of brainstorming ,I have been found the solution.

1. Execute `Insert` statement

   ```
   insert into ClientReportNewOrder select * from ClientReportNewOrder_import
   ```
2. After insert record update record by `Dynamic` query like below.

   ```
   DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX)
   SELECT  @qry =  COALESCE( @qry + ';', '') +
   'UPDATE ClientReportNewOrder SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = NULL 
   WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = ''''' 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
   WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar') and   TABLE_NAME='ClientReportNewOrder '

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry
   ```

And follows above steps, I have been able to resolved the issue.

If any one have good technique for achieve same please post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `bcp` but if you are inserting using SQL query (`INSERT .. SELECT` construct) directly like below

```
insert into ClientReportNewOrder
    select * from ClientReportNewOrder_import
```

Then you can use either `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` function to get around this like below (a sample, considering that `col3` having `NULL`)

```
insert into ClientReportNewOrder(col1,col2,col3)
    select col1,col2,ISNULL(col3,'') from ClientReportNewOrder_import
```

Comment: I know about these functions but my table have lots of column.

Comment: I don't see any shortcut here except using a `before trigger` or `instead of trigger` as an alternative.

Comment: Hi rahul can you make dynamic query which takes each column name form table and concatenate with Isnull and insert table.

Comment: Yes you can but that would be same as doing what I have posted in answer and at least to me looks unnecessary but finally it's your decision since it's your problem to solve. I am just giving suggestion; what's to be implemented is up to you.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I got a solution of my question please review and let me know if we can improve answer.

Comment: Looks good. if that works fine for you without any perf hit then good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger on the table "ClientReportNewOrder".

The trigger which you can create is "Instead of" trigger on the table and check if the value in there is null, then you can force that to write "">

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsteadOfInsert ON dbo.Yourtable
INSTEAD OF Insert
declare @value varchar(55)
BEGIN 
 BEGIN TRAN

 if(@value is Null)
     begin
        Insert into Yourtable (Value) values (@value);
        COMMIT;
    End
End
```

Hope this helps.